# Use Calendar.Date to create dummy data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a table of schedules, using `Calendar.Date` to generate empty 'cells'.

Query:

```
select  c.Date, d.DriverId, d.RouteId, d.StartTime
FROM    Calendar c
left outer join
(
  select 'ABC' DriverId, 101 RouteId, cast('2019-08-26 08:30:00.000' as datetime) StartTime
  union all
  select 'ABC' DriverId, 101 RouteId, cast('2019-08-29 08:30:00.000' as datetime) StartTime
  union all
  select 'DEF' DriverId, 201 RouteId, cast('2019-08-27 11:30:00.000' as datetime) StartTime
) d ON d.StartTime >= c.Date AND d.StartTime < DATEADD(DAY, 1, c.Date)
WHERE   1=1
and     c.date between '08/26/19' and '08/29/19'
```

Results:

```
Date,DriverId,RouteId,StartTime
2019-08-26 00:00:00.000,ABC,101,2019-08-26 08:30:00.000
2019-08-27 00:00:00.000,DEF,201,2019-08-27 11:30:00.000
2019-08-28 00:00:00.000,,,
2019-08-29 00:00:00.000,ABC,101,2019-08-29 08:30:00.000
```

Desired:

```
Date,DriverId,RouteId,StartTime
2019-08-26 00:00:00.000,ABC,101,2019-08-26 08:30:00.000
2019-08-26 00:00:00.000,DEF,,
2019-08-27 00:00:00.000,ABC,,
2019-08-27 00:00:00.000,DEF,201,2019-08-27 11:30:00.000
2019-08-28 00:00:00.000,ABC,,
2019-08-28 00:00:00.000,DEF,,
2019-08-29 00:00:00.000,ABC,101,2019-08-29 08:30:00.000
2019-08-29 00:00:00.000,DEF,,
```

A `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select  c.Date, d.DriverId, d.RouteId, d.StartTime
FROM    Calendar c
cross join
(
  select 'ABC' DriverId, 101 RouteId, cast('2019-08-26 08:30:00.000' as datetime) StartTime
  union all
  select 'ABC' DriverId, 101 RouteId, cast('2019-08-29 08:30:00.000' as datetime) StartTime
  union all
  select 'DEF' DriverId, 201 RouteId, cast('2019-08-27 11:30:00.000' as datetime) StartTime
) d 
WHERE   1=1
and     c.date between '08/26/19' and '08/29/19'
```

doesn't produce the desire results:

```
Date,DriverId,RouteId,StartTime
2019-08-26 00:00:00.000,ABC,101,2019-08-26 08:30:00.000
2019-08-26 00:00:00.000,ABC,101,2019-08-29 08:30:00.000
2019-08-26 00:00:00.000,DEF,201,2019-08-27 11:30:00.000
2019-08-27 00:00:00.000,ABC,101,2019-08-26 08:30:00.000
2019-08-27 00:00:00.000,ABC,101,2019-08-29 08:30:00.000
2019-08-27 00:00:00.000,DEF,201,2019-08-27 11:30:00.000
2019-08-28 00:00:00.000,ABC,101,2019-08-26 08:30:00.000
2019-08-28 00:00:00.000,ABC,101,2019-08-29 08:30:00.000
2019-08-28 00:00:00.000,DEF,201,2019-08-27 11:30:00.000
2019-08-29 00:00:00.000,ABC,101,2019-08-26 08:30:00.000
2019-08-29 00:00:00.000,ABC,101,2019-08-29 08:30:00.000
2019-08-29 00:00:00.000,DEF,201,2019-08-27 11:30:00.000
```

Is there a way to achieve the results without having to resort to `T/SQL`?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish in your expected results? The expected output is odd. Also, what do you mean without having to resort to T-SQL? You tagged this question as SQL Server?

Comment: @dfundako, I don't want to create a procedure with #tables unless necessary.  I tagged it with `sql-server` in case there is MSSQL-specific syntax that would be useful.

Comment: @dfundako, I want to know if a `DriverId` has a `RouteId` for each of specified `Date` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can cross apply and take the max start time:

```
SELECT 
c.val, 
d.driverid, 
MAX(CASE WHEN c.val <> CAST(CAST(d.starttime AS DATE) AS DATETime) THEN NULL else d.routeid end) AS routeid,
MAX(CASE WHEN c.val <> CAST(CAST(d.starttime AS DATE) AS DATETime) THEN NULL else d.starttime end) AS start_time

FROM calendar c
CROSS APPLY driverstuff d

GROUP BY c.val, d.driverid
ORDER BY c.val
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select c.dte, d.DriverId, drs.RouteId, drs.StartTime
from (values ('ABC'), ('DEF')) d(DriverId) cross join
     (values (convert(date, '2019-08-26')), (convert(date, '2019-08-27')), (convert(date, '2019-08-28')), (convert(date, '2019-08-29'))
     ) c(dte) left join
     (values ('ABC', 101, cast('2019-08-26 08:30:00.000' as datetime)),
             ('ABC', 101, cast('2019-08-29 08:30:00.000' as datetime)),
             ('DEF', 201, cast('2019-08-27 11:30:00.000' as datetime)
     ) drs(DriverId, RouteId, StartTime)
     on drs.driverId = d.driverId and
        drs.StartTime >= c.dte and drs.StartTime < dateadd(day, 1, c.dte)
order by dte, driverid,
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=298c816539caf078e41de00f0b591476) is a db<>fiddle.

You can use a calendar table, but I don't see a need for that for this example.

Comment: Get a unique list of `DriverId`, `CROSS JOIN` the desired `Date`s, then `LEFT JOIN` the routes to populate the remaining fields.  Makes sense.

Comment: This should be more efficient than the other answer under most circumstances.